# Why is not redirected to home after login?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

`auth()->attempt($credentials, true)` is working but its redirecting to `/login` however! I didn't do anything like that in middleware for example. Can anyone knows what is going on? Thanks

**LoginController**

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validateLogin($request);

    $credentials = $request->only('email', 'password');

    if (auth()->attempt($credentials, true)) {
        // return 'it works';
        return redirect()->to('/');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withErrors([
        'msg' => trans('labels.others.credentials_not_valid')
    ]);
}
```

**Routes**

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::get('/', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@index']);
});
```

Comment: I've seen in the documentation that maybe you should use `return redirect()->intended('/')`

Comment: I tried that too. Its not working

Comment: what does `HomeController@index` method look like?

Comment: Okay I just checked that method and thats the problem, thanks. Its easier to blame Taylor Otwell than myself. Have a nice day yall

Comment: Can you post your solution in case someone encounter the same problem ?